# Whats in the mempool? Was wondering if there are listed properties that anyone can view it

Tags: solidity, uniswap, txpool

If you send a transaction and it is in the mempool, what are the properties in the transaction of the memool?

I was wondering if you can get the address of the sender in the mempool. What else can be found in the mempool?

Can the frontrunner or MEV bot change the input parameters of the function call which is in the transaction of the mempool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dev advocate at [Chainstack](https://chainstack.com/) here.

The Ethereum mempool, or transaction pool, contains all transactions broadcast to the network but not yet included in a block. Anyone can view the contents of the mempool, either through a blockchain explorer or by querying an Ethereum node directly.

Let's address your questions:

1. **Properties of Transactions in the Mempool**: Transactions in the mempool are generally in the 'pending' state, meaning waiting to be included in a block. They will have all validated transaction properties except for the fields related to the block.

   - **From Address**: The address of the sender. This is publicly visible in the mempool.
   - **To Address**: The recipient's address (or the contract being interacted with).
   - **Value**: The amount of Ether being transferred.
   - **Gas Price**: The price (in Ether) the sender is willing to pay per unit of gas.
   - **Gas Limit**: The maximum amount of gas the sender is willing to consume for the transaction.
   - **Nonce**: A sequential number tied to each transaction by the same sender to prevent double-spending.
   - **Input Data**: This includes the function call and parameters for smart contract interactions.
2. **Visibility of Sender's Address**: You can view the sender's address in the mempool. This is part of the transaction data that is necessary for the transaction to be processed. The point above generally shows the other fields you can see from transactions in the mempool.
3. **MEV Bots and Frontrunning**: Regarding the alteration of transaction parameters by frontrunners or MEV (Miner Extractable Value) bots:

   - MEV bots and frontrunners do not change the input parameters of existing transactions in the mempool. Instead, they place their own transactions with higher gas fees to get them mined preferentially.
   - The input parameters of a transaction are immutable once the transaction is signed and broadcast. No external party can alter these parameters without altering the transaction hash, which would invalidate the transaction.
   - Frontrunners and MEV bots usually engage in practices like bidding up gas prices to have their transactions processed first or executing transactions based on the anticipated outcome of pending transactions.

### How to see pending transactions

There are various ways to see pending transactions and their data. Here I'll show you how to listen to pending transactions using web3.js and a WebSocket connection to an Ethereum node.

Install `web3.js`

```sh
npm i web3@1.10.0
```

In a new file named `index.js` paste the following code

```js
const Web3 = require("web3");
const NODE_URL =
  "CHAINSTACK_WSS_URL";
const web3 = new Web3(NODE_URL);

async function subscribeTopendingTransactions() {
  try {
    // Create a new subscription to the 'pendingTransactions' event
    const subscription = await web3.eth.subscribe("pendingTransactions");

    // Attach event listeners to the subscription object
    subscription.on("connected", handleConnected);
    subscription.on("data", handleNewPending);
    subscription.on("error", handleError);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Error subscribing to new blocks: ${error}`);
  }
}

// Use this function to unsuscribe and exit the program
function unsubscribe() {
  subscription.unsubscribe(function (error, success) {
    if (success) console.log("Successfully unsubscribed!");
    return process.exit(1);
  });
}

/* Fallback functions to react to the different events */

// Event listener that logs a message when the subscription is connected
function handleConnected(subscriptionId) {
  console.log(`New subscription: ${subscriptionId}`);
}

// Event listener that logs the received pendingTransactions
async function handleNewPending(transactionHash) {
  try {
    const transaction = await web3.eth.getTransaction(transactionHash);
    console.log(transaction);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Error getting transaction: ${error}`);
  }
}

// Event listener that logs any errors that occur
function handleError(error) {
  console.error(`Error receiving new blocks: ${error}`);
}

subscribeTopendingTransactions();
```

Add your node WSS to `const NODE_URL`.

Run the script, and you'll see a stream of the pending transactions from the mempool.

Here is an example of the result:

```sh
{
  blockHash: null,
  blockNumber: null,
  from: '0xdD091739143cA168EB16671AE8D0A9D3ce7D4801',
  gas: 42000,
  gasPrice: '36277017745',
  hash: '0x5de0b73306f83d2b7d4d2e6be14c2cfff31424eebe1d487a1193ab2fbb62f0b3',
  input: '0x',
  nonce: 17,
  to: '0xe1aF73bc888201e995e5705CBFB1dc9bC491990D',
  transactionIndex: null,
  value: '581479073209527400',
  type: 0,
  chainId: '0x1',
  v: '0x25',
  r: '0x336092a5e0462856fddc01f7b28f90d27610d8c3888b68bdd94b3e827d4123f1',
  s: '0x43c80a7e1f66e30bb966c3dbd59b29e04d6e0620544cf6473f76c3535185d4ad'
}
```

> You can learn more about the subscription methods and getting real-time data from a node from those articles:
>
> - [subscribe("pendingTransactions") | Ethereum](https://docs.chainstack.com/reference/ethereum-subscribependingtransactions)
> - [Handle real-time data using WebSocket with JavaScript and Python](https://docs.chainstack.com/docs/handle-real-time-data-using-websockets-with-javascript-and-python)
>
> Or those articles about the mempool itself
>
> - [Metamask transactions tutorial – a developer’s guide to transactions in Ethereum mempool](https://chainstack.com/a-developers-guide-to-the-transactions-in-mempool-metamask-edition/)
> - [Blockchain transactions in Ethereum mempool – Coding edition](https://chainstack.com/a-developers-guide-to-the-transactions-in-mempool-code-edition/)

Feel free to reach out to you if you have any questions!

Comment: That's a commitment in elaborating~